# Does pushing to heroku interrupt currently running rake tasks in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Suppose a rake rask is running (via heroku scheduler or manually started with something like `heroku run rake myraketask`).

If the app was pushed to *while* the rake rask was running, would the app update and the rake task continue to run as usual, or would the rake task stop? (note: suppose the push was a small change to the view, not a change to anything major like db schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a new release won't affect running tasks, because those tasks are run as [one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) which are not affected by automatic restarts - they'll continue as normal until they're terminated.

After the release, any future one-off dynos will be spawned running the latest version.

Comment: Great, that's what I was hoping for!